# Laravel model user custom binding "/users/me/xxx"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I have routes with user binding like

```
Route::get('users/{user}/posts', [PostController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('users/{user}/comments', [CommentController::class, 'index']);
```

So I can use `/users/1/posts`, `/users/5/posts` etc, and in controller it's automatically available thanks to model binding

```
public function index(User $user)
{
    dd($user);
}
```

But for current logged user I want to make possible to also use `/me/` instead ID, like `/users/me/posts`

Is there a way to make it without defining separate controller methods where I would have to find user manually, and without duplicating all routes? So is it possible to "extend" default Laravel model binding globally?

Comment: you could do an explicit binding with your own look up logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe using a fixed route parameter like this is the most sustainable solution, especially if this is a shared code base. It will involve some repeated code, but makes it immediately clear what routes are available. And you can predefine the grouping callback to avoid repeating the route definitions.

```php
$routeGroup = function ($r) {
    $r->get('posts', [PostController::class, 'index']);
    $r->get('comments', [CommentController::class, 'index']);
};

Route::prefix('users/{user}')->group($routeGroup);
Route::prefix('users/me')->group($routeGroup);
```

And then make the parameter optional in your controller method.

```php
public function index(User $user = null)
{
    $user = $user ?? Auth::user();
    dd($user);
}
```

---

Another possibility is overriding the `resolveRouteBinding` method on your model. If you go with this method (or Patricus' solution) I'd suggest leaving comments in the route file explaining what you've done.

```php
class User extends Model {
    public function resolveRouteBinding($value, $field = null): ?self
    {
        return $value === 'me'
            ? Auth::user()
            : parent::resolveRouteBinding($value, $field);
    }
}
```

Comment: The user said "without declaring another route" but I agree 100% your solution is the best solution, it is just another route and that's it...

Comment: Thanks. Both solutions are good, but I'm going with resolveRouteBinding(). @patricus solution also solves my problem but it's more clear to having this defined in user model instead boot(). So resolveRouteBinding() is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you just need to use [explicit route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-the-resolution-logic) instead of the default implicit binding. No need to change your routes or your controllers.

In your `RouteServiceProvider::boot()` method, you can add the following binding for the `user` parameter:

```
// use App\Models\User;
// use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
// use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

public function boot()
{
    Route::bind('user', function ($value) {
        if ($value == 'me') {
            return Auth::user();
        }

        return User::findOrFail($value);
    });
}
```

Now all your routes with the `{user}` parameter defined will use that function to bind the `User` model in the route.

You may want to update the function to be able to handle case sensitivity, or handle when the route is accessed as a guest, but that's up to your implementation details.

Comment: Nice, I woke up in the middle of the night and realized there was a better option than my answer of adding more routes; looks like there's a few options.

Comment: @miken32 I would argue there are better solutions than adding a new route, as they could be more complex, but adding 1 more route is way more visible and less obfuscated, your solution is the best (from a professional standpoint)

Comment: @matiaslauriti yes I think there's a lot of value in having it show up in `artisan route:list` rather than having things tucked away in a method somewhere